# negation of continuity over a set

Tags: real-analysis, logic, continuity

Let $f : M \mapsto N$ be a continuous function on $M$. Are the following definition of continuity and its negation both correct?

$\forall x_0 \in M, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta(x_0, \epsilon) > 0$ such that $\forall x \in M$ such that $d_M(x_0, x) < \delta(x_0, \epsilon)$, we have $d_N\left( f(x_0), f( x) \right) < \epsilon$

**Negation:** $\exists x_0 \in M$ and $\exists \epsilon > 0$, such that $\forall \delta > 0$, $\exists y \in M$, $y \neq x_0$ such that $d_M\left(x_0, y \right) < \delta$ but $d_N\left( f(x_0), f(y) \right) \geq \epsilon$.

Comment: That looks correct to me. Minor typo in first statement: $d_N(f(x_0,x))$ should be $d_N(f(x_0), f(x))$.